# PostgreSQL service start failed on CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, centos, master-slave-replication

Installed PostgreSQL using:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
```

PostgreSQL version: 9.2.18

When start service:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Got error:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  postgresql.service
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The `journalctl -xe` detail:

```
-- Unit postgresql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
 7月 19 04:17:04 node2 systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
 7月 19 04:17:04 node2 systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
 7月 19 04:17:04 node2 polkitd[19772]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:27133:53830492 (system bus name :1.405, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationA
 7月 19 04:19:33 node2 polkitd[19772]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:27165:53845472 (system bus name :1.406 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object pat
 7月 19 04:19:33 node2 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
-- Subject: Unit postgresql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql.service has begun starting up.
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 pg_ctl[27187]: pg_ctl: could not start server
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 pg_ctl[27187]: Examine the log output.
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
 7月 19 04:19:34 node2 polkitd[19772]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:27165:53845472 (system bus name :1.406, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationA
lines 2850-2910/2910 (END)
```

Run `systemctl status PostgreSQL.service`, got this information:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-19 04:30:26 EDT; 42min ago
  Process: 27285 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 27280 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26640 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: What are your PostgreSQL logs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 steps before being abble to connect to a PostgreSQL Database:

- Install PostgreSQL
- Create the data cluster ($PGDATA)
- Start the server

You already installed PostgreSQL, you need now to create the cluster. The `initdb` tool is what you need.

You will find documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/creating-cluster.html).

It might be confusing because when you're under a debian based distros, `apt` and perl wrappers do every steps for you.

Comment: Thank you. I did all of those. I followed this guide to do the replication: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps. After I created a `recovery.conf` file and added this to it: `trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'`, the `service PostgreSQL start` command didn't work. I think it's the reason.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention any of that...

Comment: After I reinstall PostgreSQL, works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the `shared_buffers` was too big that cased the failed state, I decrease it to 128MB and restarted then worked fine, my case was I made a copy of the data directory after an OS crash to a new OS .

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour to me. In my case there were wrong permissions on PGDATA. It was logged only in detail in /var/log/messages. chmod 700 data helped to get the standby node up and running.